# prevent auto-complete expansion in emacs except for explicit binding

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I want auto-complete menu to show automatically while typing but never expand except if explicitly requested (return or M-tab or such). I type very fast and I only want to potentially expand if I don't know what I want or there's a very long completion. I cannot seem to be able to prevent expansion when a single option is available in the menu and this causes big problems when there are already characters on the line right of the cursor.

Auto-complete menu shows fine. With each character the options get more narrow. Problem shows when a single option is left - the menu disappears and the overlay expansion shows (obscuring existing characters to the right of the cursor). When I type one more character the expansion takes effect but it is broken up with the remaining characters of the expansion as a suffix to the existing line. If the one more character I typed was NOT the one in the suggested expansion things still break but without the rest of the suggestion.

This is very inconvenient as I usually type very fast and trigger broken completions. I would like to have the menu always show automatically but expansions NEVER take effect except explicitly (I slow down my typing when I'm unsure what I want to type.

I tried all the options I found in the documentation but I just cannot prevent expansions from taking effect. I want to completely disable expansions (except for explicit expansion).